# CDATE behaviour not consistent with documentation (for me)

Tags: vb.net

Please take a look at the following webpage: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3eaydw6e.aspx:

"
You must enclose a Date literal within number signs (# #). You must specify the date value in the format M/d/yyyy, for example #5/31/1993#. This requirement is independent of your locale and your computer's date and time format settings.
"

Now see the code below:

```
Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
        Dim str As String = "1-2-1999"
        Dim dte As Date = CDate(str)
        MsgBox(dte.Month)
    End Sub
```

**Questions:**

1) The messagebox prints: 2.  I would expect it to print 1 based on the following quote: "You must specify the date value in the format M/d/yyyy".
2) The string literal is: 1-2-1999 and not #1-2-1999#, yet the quote says: "You must enclose a Date literal within number signs (# #)"

Comment: there is no need to create a string only to convert it to date, just create the date directly (usually, it is the other way around) `Dim dte As Date = New Date(1999, 1, 2)` (Y, M, D) order

Comment: @Plutonix thanks, the date is taken from a database field so it would be difficult to parse as 1999,1,2.  Are you able to answer my question?

Comment: does the database have the date as a Date type or as a string?

Comment: @Plutonix , it is a date type in the database.

Comment: then you should be good to go, a date is a date.  the problem is trying to use strings as dates.  `myDate = dbObject("OrderDate")` should work fine.  A Brit will see it as "D/M/Y", a Yank as "M/D/Y" when displayed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From MSDN: `You must enclose a Date literal within number signs (# #). You must specify the date value in the format M/d/yyyy, for example #5/31/1993#.`  That isnt what you did.  You created a string, then converted it to a date.  To create a `Date` variable using a literal:

```
Dim dte As Date = #1/2/1999#
Console.WriteLine(dte.Month)      ' prints 1
```

Comment: Thanks +1.  One other thing.  Please look at this webpage: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/system.datetime.aspx.  DATE and DATETIME seem to be used interchangeably.  Do you know why?

Comment: `Date` is a Net thing in mscorlib, `DateTime` is defined as a basic System Type/structure, but I thing they are just using Date as shorthand for `DateTime`.  There is also a `DateAndTime` defined in the VB namespace

Comment: would you use date or datetime?

Comment: I dont think there is any difference.  the constructor for date (like I used in first comment) takes time variables too.  I think DateTime is basically the structure Date implements.  Intellisence gives the same definition for them

Comment: I see, like int64 is the strict that long is implemented with. Thanks.